# Matching on "broken" strings

Tags: python

Lets say I have [this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/Rk5hhVVTRAi9aYM6c10i2A.png) image. It is supposed to say "Box Logo Hooded Sweatshirt" and "Red", but obviously they have messed it up.

How would I deal with this insertion of random characters when trying to scrape and match on keywords?

Currently this is how I am matching (I match on a list of strings):

```
        product_name = piece.contents[0].contents[1].text
        product_color = piece.contents[0].contents[2].text

        print(product_name)
        print(product_color)
        if all(i in product_name.lower() for i in keywords) and all(i in product_color.lower() for i in color):
            found = True
            log('Found Product: ' + product_name + ' - ' + product_color, 'success')
```

Comment: `&#65279` is not a random char sequence but is the unicode for 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE'. You could get rid of this by replacing this by `''` (emtpy string)

Comment: Thank you. Are there any other unicode characters that are like this that I should also watch out for?

Comment: FWIW, although that codepoint is 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' it's commonly used as the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), but the BOM is normally only used at the start of UTF-encoded Unicode files. Inside a file, it still operates as a no-break zero-width space.

Comment: Your input is the text you've taken a picture of, right? Not an image of text you need to OCR first?

Comment: It is the actual text, correct. Not a picture

Comment: In that case it'd be better to paste the text into your question, rather than link to a picture of it. With the input, people can actually test solutions (also the link can't rot)